# CKeditor 5 with Laravel image upload

Tags: laravel, ckeditor5

In my Laravel application, I like to work with CKEditor 5 to enter descriptions with image upload. When I paste an image, there is always a Status 419. When I add a `public function __construct()` it returns the value.

Controller:

```
class TaskController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
 */

public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    dd($request);
}

public function addImage(Request $request)
{
    dd($request);
}
}
```

Why it returns only the request on the `__construct` function and on the `addImage` function, it returns the 419?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable CSRF protection for this route.